# Retornar valor de Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises

Tenho a seguinte código:

```
  const retorno_valores = []
     result.forEach(   value => {
        var reader = getReader(conn, 10)
        retorno_valores.push({reader})
      });


const getReader=  async (conn, cdReader)=>{
   const dados = await med(conn, cdReader)
   return dados
}


const med = ( conn, leitor  ) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        conn.query('SELECT ip FROM reader WHERE ip = ?', [leitor], (error, result)=>{
            if(error){                
                reject(error)
            }
            resolve(result[0].ip_controlado)
        })        
    })
}
```

Quando dou um `console.log('reader', reader)` na variável `reader` ele mostra da seguinte forma:

```
reader Promise { <pending> }
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para obter o valor não a promise

Já fiz assim

```
     const retorno_valores = []
     result.forEach(  async value => {
        var reader = await getReader(conn, 10)
        retorno_valores.push({reader})
      });
```

Mas não consigo recuperar fora do foreach o array `retorno_valores`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente utilizar um `map` para transformar cada chamada da função `getReader` em uma promessa e depois utilizar a função `Promise.all` em conjunto com o `await` para obter um `array` de valores:

```
const promessas = result.map(async value => getReader(conn, 10));
const valores = await Promise.all(promessas);
```

---

> [**Promise​.all()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
>
> O método `Promise.all(iterable)` retorna uma única `Promise` que resolve quando todas as `promises` no argumento iterável forem resolvidas ou quando o iterável passado como argumento não contém `promises`. É rejeitado com o motivo da primeira `promise` que foi rejeitada.

---

> [**Funções assíncronas**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas)
>
> A declaração **async function** define uma função assíncrona, que retorna um objeto [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction).
>
> Você também pode definir funções assíncronas usando uma [expressão async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function).
>
> Quando uma função assíncrona é chamada, ela retorna uma [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Quando a função assíncrona retorna um valor, a `Promise` será resolvida com o valor retornado. Quando a função assíncrona lança uma exceção ou algum valor, a `Promise` será rejeitada com o valor lançado.
>
> Uma função assíncrona pode conter uma expressão [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), que pausa a execução da função assíncrona e espera pela resolução da `Promise` passada, e depois retoma a execução da função assíncrona e retorna o valor resolvido.

Comment: Sabe o que eu achei interessante? É que só precisei adicionar isso aqui `const promessas = result.map...` e isso aqui `await Promise.all(promises);` e continuar com meu código `resolve(retorno_valores)` que funcionou... Por que não precisei do retorno?

Comment: @adventistaam porque em uma promessa você não precisa retornar já que a estrutura não é `topdown` e não tem como você avaliar dessa forma que a execução foi finalizada