# JS - Objeto destino como argumento da função

Tags: javascript, funções, argumento

Venho do C# e estou com dificuldade de entender esse conceito de passar o objeto de destino como argumento da função.

Nos exemplos abaixo, o primeiro funciona, como faço pra atribuir o resultado da função ao objeto sem ter que abrir um novo escopo?

```js
function loadData(){

    $.getJSON('json/acompFatAutomatico.json', function(data) {          
        alert(data[0].Codigo);
    });
}


function loadData(){

    var data = $.getJSON('json/acompFatAutomatico.json');
    alert(data[0].Codigo);

}
```

Comment: está tentando usar um método assíncrono de forma síncrona, se não conhece esses conceitos estude o que são. Fazer esse codigo de forma síncrona sem *promise* vai **bloquear** o código enquanto não tiver o resultado, o que é uma **péssima** experiência para o usuário, ter seu navegador bloqueado. Se ainda assim quer, passe como parâmetro no `getSON` isso `async: false`. E *" passar o objeto de destino como argumento da função"* não é bem o que acontece ai, esse `function(data)` é o retorno de uma *promise*, um código assíncrono, um conceito parecido com `Thread`e `Task` no `c#`

Comment: o comentário ficou longo, se precisar de mais esclarecimentos posso escrever uma resposta com isso e mais detalhes

Comment: Entendi, @RicardoPontual, muito obrigado pelo direcionamento.

Comment: @RicardoPontual, qual o termo correto para esse tipo de escrita? Realmente preciso estudar essa forma de passar outra função como argumento.

Comment: no primeiro exemplo a function espera o retorno de um *promise*, que é o retorno da chamada assíncrona, mas também pode ser chamado de *callback*. Essas duas perguntas abordam isso, é uma boa leitura:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/398821/retornar-valor-de-promise?  
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168824/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-promise-e-callback?

Answer (score 0):

Essa função ***getJSON***, aparentemente, recebe 2 parâmetros: uma **string** (rota para buscar os dados), e uma outra **função** para manipular os dados obtidos. Ou seja, se ela já utiliza de outra função para manipular os dados, não tem razão para ela retornar esses dados de "forma direta", por isso o segundo exemplo acaba não funcionando.

Quando uma função é usada como parâmetro de outra, denominamos como uma "função de **Callback**".

Se você quer manipular os dados obtidos, independente da manipulação (no caso especifico, apenas inserir o valor em outra variável) deves colocar essa manipulação dentro da função de **Callback**, como já foi feito no primeiro caso. Contudo tem mais meios de fazer isso, como utilizando **Arrow Functions**.

---

Alguns exemplos:

```
function loadData1(){
  let myData

  $.getJSON('json/acompFatAutomatico.json', function(data) {
    myData = data
  })
}

function loadData2(){
  let myData
    
  function setMyData(data) {
    myData = data
  }

  $.getJSON('json/acompFatAutomatico.json', setMyData)
}

function loadDataComArrowFunction(){
  let myData

  $.getJSON('json/acompFatAutomatico.json', (data) => { myData = data })
}
```